# How do I ensure that a java object is serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm using a 3rd party library that asks to use only serializable object with its methods. How do I ensure that a java object is serializable ?

Sometimes my objects are just a list, a string or a simple POJO.

Comment: Your 3rd party library can do the check for you if they mandate it ;)

Answer (score 4):

If it implements `Serializable`.

Comment: Being that there are no methods in Serializable to implement, is there any other overhead to ensure it actually is serializable?

Comment: what if I create a new Object made up of an java.util.ArrayList, Integer & other serializable objects & primitive fields, do I need to also make the created object as implements Serializable ? Is it bad if I just put implements Serializable in all of my POJO classes ?

Comment: First question: Yes, you have to implement the interface, because otherwise Java assumes, you don't want your objects to be serializable (conscience decision making etc.)
Second: You can have the problem that at some point in time, someone has the idea to serialize some objects and they are not deserializable, because certain parts of objects CAN be non-serializable and the default implementing prevents you from thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

make your class `implements` `Serializable` interface

and don't forgot to add `serialversionuid`

Comment: what if I create a new Object made up of an `java.util.ArrayList`, `Integer` & other serializable objects & primitive fields, do I need to also make the created object as `implements Serializable` ? Is it bad if I just put `implements Serializable` in all of my POJO classes  ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will tell you if a class from Java standard library implements a particular interface. Look under **All Implemented Interfaces**. For example, the String class implements `Serializable`, `CharSequence`, and `Comparable<String>`.

If you create your own class, make it serializable like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {}
```

Your class can only be serializable if every object inside of it is *also* serializable. If your class contains a non-serializable object, most modern IDEs will alert you, or the compiler will simply throw an error when you try to build.